# How to use if else in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a part of the registration form that I wish to hide from third party viewers. Basically, it can only be seen on registration and the user of the account. I thought this is the correct syntax but it gavve me a `TemplateSyntaxError` `Could not parse the remainder: '(request.user.is_authenticated' from '(request.user.is_authenticated'`

```
{% if (request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.account_type == 1) or not request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Comment: Just remove the brackets (Such syntax won't work in templates). Anyway operator precedence is with you. and is evaluated first, or later.

Comment: it would conflict with authenticated and not authenticated if I remove them

Comment: From the documentation _"Use of both **and** and **or** clauses within the same tag is allowed, with **and** having higher precedence than **or**"_. your code would be fine just remove the bracket...

Comment: Also from the documentation _"Use of actual parentheses in the **if** tag is invalid syntax. If you need them to indicate precedence, you should use nested **if** tags."_

Comment: @Abdul has said it well. Remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if), but Abdul Aziz Barkat`s answer is right, just try to remove brackets ().